# Data binding not working properly in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I created a custom ControlTemplate as a validation error template. I wanted to hide the text block when the adorned element(A textbox) is disabled using the built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter converter. The problem now is that the text block would not be hidden when the textbox got disabled.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Name="ErrorText" FontStyle="Italic" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Foreground="red" Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource b2v}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="ErrorAdorner"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: This article might be helpful to you. [How to: Implement Binding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN) Furthermore, changing the binding path `IsEnabled` to `AdornedElement.IsEnabled` or `AdornedElement.(Validation.HasError)` might work.

Comment: @Songpl You are god sent. I changed the binding path from **IsEnabled** to **AdornedElement.IsEnabled** and it worked! Thank you.